# Very slow MongoDB find query

Tags: mongodb

I am having troubles with this simple query which takes a few minutes.

`db.data_items.find({'observation_target.observation_target_id': 2190}).limit(20000)`

The explain output shows that the query uses the right index:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor observation_target.observation_target_id_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 20000,
    "nscannedObjects" : 20000,
    "nscanned" : 20000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 20000,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 20000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 4515,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 174037,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "observation_target.observation_target_id" : [
            [
                2190,
                2190
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "xxx.mongolab.com:49710",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Moreover, when limiting the number of results successively to 2000, 4000, 6000 ... 20000, each individual query is fast.  The MongoDB version is 2.6.5.

Comment: What is the average size of your documents (eg. `db.observation_target.stats().avgObjSize`) and what type of plan are you on at MongoLab? Perhaps at 20,000 documents you are hitting a ceiling on the resources that have been provisioned for your plan level.

Comment: I think we have a memory problem here. The data set seems not to be in RAM. With the sequential increase, it most likely is. The number of yields is accordingly high.